# My vagrant instant is not working

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Got this error while running `vagrant up`:

> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>   Command: ["startvm", "df5a654c-fa01-499a-ac48-e4161821edc7", "--type", "headless"]
>   Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Can someone help me with this ? Vagrantfile is already ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the question has already been answered here:

[Error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746462/error-vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disa)

Here is also a youtube link for the fix: https://youtu.be/ERnKeUMEFXU

Answer (score 1):

go to cmd--->Type the command-->Systeminfo.exe-->Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
**Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: No**
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

if this is no

Goto Settings-->Update&Security-->Recovery-->Advanced Restart-->Troubleshoot-->Advanced
-->UEFI firmware--->System Configuartion---Enable virtualization---Save and Exit.